# How disable strange axis view?

Tags: 3d-view, axis, gizmo

Don't understand how disable this axis view

[image: axis]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have *Origins* enabled in the *Transform menu*.
Just uncheck it and those annoying axis will disappear.

(The gizmo shows for each of your 583 selected objects)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under *Overlays* turn off all display normals:

[image]